# Android GIS library trend

Tags: mobile, gis, trend

I think there are lots of open source library for mobile gis which can working on offline including arcgis, qgis, nextgis, osmand, etc.

Is there any more library?
What is feature of these libraries and which library widely use?

Thanks is advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Gdal

Raster and Vector data reader engine

http://www.gdal.org/

- geoserver

Java-based software server that allows users to view and edit geospatial data

http://geoserver.org/

- Leaflet

JavaScript Library for Mobile Friendly Interactive Maps

http://leafletjs.com/